# compact(): Undefined variable: getChoices

Tags: laravel

Here's the idea I have this code :

```
$question_one = Questions::orderBy('publish_time', 'desc')->first();
 if (!empty($question_one)) {
   $getChoices =  question_choices::where('questions_id', '=', $question_one->id)->get();
 }

 return view('mySite.after_login', compact('getChoices','question_one'));
```

when table Questions is not empty , the code is run and all things is good , but when I delete all query from table Questions , suddenly show me this error :

> compact(): Undefined variable: getChoices

So I need to say if empty don't pass it or any good solve you suggest me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a breaking change introduced in PHP 7.3 with the `compact()` method.  It no longer accepts non-initialized variables into the method. To fix, initialize the variable before sending to compact.  Like this:

```
$getChoices = null;  // <-- Just init the variable to null before the if-check
$question_one = Questions::orderBy('publish_time', 'desc')->first();
if (!empty($question_one)) {
    $getChoices =  question_choices::where('questions_id', '=', $question_one->id)->get();
 }

return view('mySite.after_login', compact('getChoices','question_one'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$getChoices` is declared in an if statement. Whenever the if condition is false it will complain about undefined variable.
You can declare it as a null above your if statement

```
$getChoices = null;
```